# Why "Unchecked cast from..."

Tags: java, unchecked-cast

I don't understand why I get an `Unchecked cast from Object to Compareable<Object>` because it is inside of a area that is only entered, if the instance is of a Compareable type. Can someone explain this to me and maybe give a solution, thanks.

My code looks like this. The problem is at line 8 and 9:

```
public int compare(Object one, Object two) {

if (one instanceof Vector && two instanceof Vector) {
  Vector<? extends Object> vOne = (Vector<?>)one;
  Vector<? extends Object> vTwo = (Vector<?>)two;
  Object oOne = vOne.elementAt(index);
  Object oTwo = vTwo.elementAt(index);

  if (oOne instanceof Comparable && oTwo instanceof Comparable) {
    Comparable<Object> cOne = (Comparable<Object>)oOne;
    Comparable<Object> cTwo = (Comparable<Object>)oTwo;
    if (ascending) {
      return cOne.compareTo(cTwo);
    } else {
      return cTwo.compareTo(cOne);
    }
  }
}
return 1;

}
```

Comment: Yes, duplicate. The accepted answer from that question directly addresses this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it produces an unchecked warning as it doesn't know that your object is `Comparable` to `Object`.  In fact it is highly unlikely that it is, e.g. `Integer` is `Comparable<Integer>` but this is the simplest way to get this code to compile

I suggest you use

```
@SuppressWarning("checked")
Comparable<Object> cOne = (Comparable<Object>)oOne;
```

or

```
Comparable cOne = (Comparable) oOne;
```

BTW, You can't just `return 1` at the end as you have you ensure that if `compare(a, b) > 0` then `compare(b, a) < 0`

Comment: It's not the cast to `Comparable` that's causing problems, it's the cast to `Comparable<Object>`. See the accepted answer from the dup, above.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Good point, in this cases the warning is valid, unless you assume that `a` and `b` will always be `Comparable` which may, or may not be correct.